# YouTube video in a Google Map Info Window

Tags: youtube, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put a youtube video into a Google Map (v3) Info Window.

It works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

It does *not* work in Safari and Chrome. In those browsers the positioning is off and the video doesn't move when you move the map. The video also gets chopped sometimes.

Here is the code that doe

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4222685, -111.8226402)
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions)
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4222685, -111.8226402);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/UmFjNiiVk9w?fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/UmFjNiiVk9w?fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>'
        })
        bubble.open(map, marker);
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
  <div id="map" style="width: 984px; height: 495px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

An example of it working fine for the Google Maps API version 2 is here http://www.virtualvideomap.com/

Also on http://maps.google.com You can see youtube videos inside the Info Window working in Chrome and Safari by clicking "More..." on the top right of the map, and then checking "Videos".

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3160

Answer (score 2):

This is a webkit bug, but you can find a solution here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/ccaaee32b89e3656/c87bb19e4662bd78#c87bb19e4662bd78

Comment: Thank you. Nevertheless, putting a youtube video in a map using the  Google Maps API version 2 works just fine in Chrome and Safari. See this site as an example http://www.virtualvideomap.com/ (You can view the source too. It's pretty easy to follow javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Got a partial solution, use the iframe embed mode sorted the problem out to me!

Hope it helps!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4222685, -111.8226402)
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions)
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(33.4222685, -111.8226402);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map
    })
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        bubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: '<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UmFjNiiVk9w?rel=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
        })
        bubble.open(map, marker);
    })
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
  <div id="map" style="width: 984px; height: 495px"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this problem by adding the style:
`iframe { -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); }`
to my css file. In my case all of the dynamic content was already inside an iFrame and I was still having this problem. I saw this transform suggestion somewhere awhile ago, but only just tried it today. I tested it in Chrome and Safari on Windows 7. There is still some position lag, but it basically works fine now.

Comment: `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` seems to work just as well.